# Change color of view but keep ripple and touch state

Tags: android, material-design

Out of the box you can get a white ripple/touch state from:
?attr/selectableItemBackground
I would like to have the ability to do any color and the ripple and the touch state just works based off the color I set.  It would be nice if I could do this via android:theme

I need this to work API 15+

I know I can do a selector and a ripple but then I would have to do a selector per color since you can not do attr in xml pre API 21.

If I set just a color to a background then ripple and touch state doesnt work.

I would just like this to be as simple and reusable as possible.

Is there something I am missing or any solution that is relatively clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've already posted is very true:

- it's not possible to create a ripple selector by only specifying a color
- it's not possible to use theme attributes in xml using API < 21

I don't think that there is anything more than just using a library or coding that by yourself. From code you can generate ripples, use theme attributes and more.

I had the same problem and I just wrote a bunch of classes for easy ripple creation. For example to get theme colors I wrote a simple class of ColorStateList:

```
public class ControlCheckedColorStateList extends ColorStateList {
    public ControlCheckedColorStateList(Context context) {
        super(new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                new int[]{}
        }, new int[]{
                getThemeColor(context, R.attr.colorPrimary),
                getThemeColor(context, R.attr.colorControl)
        });
    }

    public static int getThemeColor(Context context, int attr) {
        Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
        TypedValue typedvalueattr = new TypedValue();
        theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedvalueattr, true);
        return typedvalueattr.resourceId != 0 ? context.getResources().getColor(typedvalueattr.resourceId) : typedvalueattr.data;
    }
}
```

Then I've added attributes for ripple color and style. I also had to override setBackground methods so setting a ripple for a view doesn't clear its background. Now setting a ripple with custom color is as simple as:

```
<carbon.widget.Button
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    app:carbon_rippleColor="#40ff0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Lots and lots of lines of code, so I don't think it's reasonable to post all of that here. If you wish, you can open any widget class from my library and check if it's what you're looking for. You can find my code on [github](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon). In case of any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I dont need ripples on older versions.  I would like a simple solution.

I am ok with it just being a touch state.  What I would like the attr/selectableItemBackground which works on I believe every view.  Then have another field that you tell the selectableitembackground what color tint to be.  Something like:
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:backgroundTint="@color/red"

Maybe I can modify the selectableItemBackgrounds code and copy it into my project.  I dont know how to find the code for that though

Comment: You can find the default selector here: http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/item_background.xml

Answer (score 2):

Ripple color seems to be controlled by `colorControlHighlight` attribute, e.g. `<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/rippleColor</item>` in your theme.

As of API 15+ support, as far as I know even AppCompat doesn't backport ripple effect because of certain limitations, see [FAQ here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). Personally I find the following "graceful degradation" sensible:

- `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` — for pre-Lollipop devices
- `?attr/selectableItemBackground` — for Lollipop and above

to use as background (foreground for cards)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes but I would like for example the ripple/touch state to be red or blue or green dependent on maybe my theme or some color I am giving to the view.  I am ok with just having a selector(touch state on older devices) but I would like the ability to easily change the color of the ripple/touch state.

Comment: Well, you can set the attribute per theme, then use this theme per activity, or even per view (although only once, when the view is inflated). Another solution that comes to mind is simply setting a color filter on background programmatically, but that probably won't work well with handling the states

Comment: How would you change the color of the touch state on API <21.

Comment: Hm... Actually, I'm not sure. I thought the attribute was applied to `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, since all I needed was gray color (selectableItemBackground had blue). But apparently it's not, so finding the right attribute would require some effort. In the end of the day one can simply create their own state drawable for <21